# Switching python interpreters for Heroku web app

Tags: python, heroku, azure-speech

**The problem**
For context:

- I have deployed an app with Heroku
- I have Python 3.9.2 running locally in VS Code vs Python 3.10.8 running on a Heroku machine

I am currently encountering the problems as mentioned on [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/1310) thread.

I have found the solution to my problem seems to be [switching python interpreters and copying my various packages to that location.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/1310#issuecomment-970342978)

However, there is little documentation on how to do this in Heroku.

Any assistance is really appreciated :)

**What I've tried**
Given the lack of documentation on the above, I've tried the following...

I found that the Heroku deployment was running on Python 3.10.8 runtime, whereas my local machine had been running 3.9.2.

I then added a runtime.txt in the root of the app's directory in Github that specified to use 3.9.2, but when I try and redeploy the build failed.

Following the Heroku logs, this leads me to:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
 !     Requested runtime 'cat runtime.txt
python-3.9.2' is not available for this stack (heroku-22).
 !     For supported versions, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

I then realise from the logs, that the build package isn't of 3.9.2 isn't supported.

I've then downloaded python 3.11.0 on my local machine (which is supported, as mentioned [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes)).

Deactivated the current virtual environment (using 3.9.2).

Created a new virtual environment.

Rerun the app locally and checked it works.

I've then added the changes to the git repo.

Then, I've tried to deploy on Heroku. I'm now getting:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
 !     Requested runtime 'cat runtime.txt
python-3.11.0' is not available for this stack (heroku-22).
 !     For supported versions, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

I then navigate to the [support documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support)

I then try and follow the support guidance around 'Checking the buildpack version', as my version of Python is supported, as per the documentation.

I run the command against my CLI which checks which buildpack version I have. I get:

```
=== [appnamegoeshere] BuildPack URL
heroku/python
```

So, I have the 'heroku/python' buildpack.

Not sure where to go from here?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I know nothing about heroku, and this seems more like a server configuration question than programming. But, is this correct output? Looks corrupt to me. `Requested runtime 'cat runtime.txt
python-3.9.2' is not available for this stack` What is "cat runtime.txt" doing in there?

Comment: @miken32 you're right it probably is a server configuration issue. Given that I'm using python, and there seem to be issues with the packages I tagged python. WRT runtime.txt issue, I was following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) documentation. It says 'To specify a Python runtime, add a runtime.txt file to your app’s root directory that declares the exact version number to use'. Which is what I did in Github...

Comment: You may want to read about ["why 'Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541).

Comment: @e-driver1, the issue is what you put _in_ your `runtime.txt`, as described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation for selecting a runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#selecting-a-runtime) says:

> To specify a Python runtime, add a `runtime.txt` file to your app's root directory that declares the exact version number to use:
>
> ```bash
> $ cat runtime.txt
> python-3.10.8
> ```

The `cat runtime` part of that is a command that you can run on many systems (Linux, macOS, etc.) to print the contents of a file out. It should *not* be included in the file.

Your `runtime.txt` should just contain the appropriate `python-x.y.z` line. At the moment, on the Heroku-22 stack you can use Python 3.9:

```
python-3.9.15
```

Python 3.10:

```
python-3.10.8
```

Or Python 3.11:

```
python-3.11.0
```

The version you use on your local machine usually just needs to match the major and minor parts: your local Python 3.9.3 should be compatible with Heroku's 3.9.15.

Note that Heroku's [list of supported Python versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes) is updated pretty frequently as new patch releases come out.

Comment: thanks - fixed it. It now builds - which is a relief. :) However, the issue now is how to resolve the 'Exception with an error code: 0x38 (SPXERR_AUDIO_SYS_LIBRARY_NOT_FOUND)' error. Which I can't follow [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/1310#issuecomment-970342978), as described above...